# Error in package 'requests' the version of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using 'requests' on python 3.4
And use this code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user')
print(r.status_code)
```

I thow exeption:

> Import Error No module named 'ndg'
>   in pyopenssl.py

as I understand it, this file is used to support python 2.
Why i am thow this exeption on python3?

Comment: can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: Are you sure you are using python3?

Answer (score 0):

This error caused enabled checkbox in Visual Studio 2015.
[image]